# Give a clicked li a background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to give just the clicked li a background color. My script gives all the clicked a background color, but I just want the clicked one.

```js
$('.tab').on("click", function() {
  $(this).css({
    backgroundColor: "#216180"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Nav">
  <li><a class="tab">aa</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab">bb</a></li>
  <li><a h class="tab">cc</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's working for me.  Or do you mean that you want to *remove* the background color from all of the elements before adding each new one?

Comment: Your code is already doing what you ask. As you can see in the snippet I created from your code, the background colour is only applied to the `.tab` which was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it correctly but you are not removing the background color from other elements which has been clicked before,

Since you have your **a** tags wrapped into **li** you should select the **li** element **(parent)** and then its **siblings** elements **(other li's)** and style its **children** which is the **a tag**

this change the background color of clicked element and remove the background color **(transparent)** from the other ones

```js
$('.tab').on("click", function() {
  $(this).css({
    backgroundColor: "#216180"
  }).parent().siblings().children().css({
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Nav">
  <li><a class="tab">aa</a></li>
  <li><a class="tab">bb</a></li>
  <li><a h class="tab">cc</a></li>
</ul>
```